# JPlayer - It doesn't work on firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, audio

In firefox, when I try to play this demo:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/
the console says:

> Media resource http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a could not be decoded.

I get this same problem with mp3 and wav files. It doesn't work on IE either. It works on chrome and opera.

I have tried changing solution: "flash" but again, this works in chrome but not in firefox. When I make it use flash, it doesn't give me any error message in the console, it just doesn't play the audio files.

The video player demo works in firefox, its just the audio player that doesn't work. Whats going on here?